# Mysql server with SSD [Intel 520 SSD]

Tags: ssd, mysql

I need to replace some slaves to my Mysql stack, I was thinking about Intel 520 SSD as storage drive.

In your opinion is it something I should follow?

At the moment the declared 30k cycles limit isn't too appealing to me, but I have no idea what this really means.
Also, what kind of configuration should I follow?
OS on normal spinning drives and data on RAIDed SSD (1+0?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cycles is for writes, not reads. If your database does mostly reading, then it will last a lot longer. SSD's are not for longevity, they are for performance. The SSD will surely help your database performance in loading large tables, or things that are not in memory (RAM). Most databases will attempt to load commonly used tables to memory since this is the fastest way to serve that data when requested (even faster than ssd). If you have a small database, a database that is not commonly slammed with I/O, or a system with a lot of RAM, then the SSD may not really show a noticeable improvement. While I always recommend having your OS separated somehow from your data, I think your OS would benefit from the SSD a lot. SSD's are great at seek times (almost no time taken really), which makes them super fast to load things to memory for use (such as binaries or programs when executed). All in all, you will see a performance gain somewhere, it just depends where/how you decide to configure it. As always, keep good backups incase one of those SSD's goes out on you.

Also, some general advice -- skip embedded raid or software raid and go get a real dedicated raid card. This will significantly increase the raid performance (having dedicated hardware such as RAM on the card and processor purely for RAID calculations), as well as make it much easier to move your raid somewhere else if you must (just get an identical raid card). The Dell Perc 5/i card is a great card that does raid 0, 1, 10 (and 5 I think) and can be found on ebay for under $60 usually. Great buy. It's older brother Perc 6/i does same raid levels but adds raid 6 as well as doubles the memory cache and other performance improvements. It can be had on ebay often for around $100. Be careful when shopping for the cards as there are two variants, the Perc 5/iR is the integrated card is really just a controller card that does software assisted raid (not true hardware raid). You can tell the cards apart since the iR's don't have the stick of memory attached on the front and no big black heatsink.